# Elementary row operation and change of matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix and let $B$ be an $n \times n$ matrix **obtained** by switching 2 rows of $A$, write $B$ in terms of $A$.

**In general** how do I do this?

I say, let $E$ be the elementary matrix obtained from $R_i \iff R_j$, where $i \ne j$.

Then what am I able to say? What are some theorems that allow me to write $B$ in terms of $A$ using elementary matrices?

Thanks

Comment: What does $E$ look like?

Answer (score 0):

By definition, when you permute two rows $i,j$ of a matrix $A$ and the result is a matrix $B$, then you have

$$B=P_{i,j}^{\sigma}·A$$

where $P_{i,j}^{\sigma}$ is the permutation matrix of rows, i.e. the identity matrix $I$ with the two rows $i, j$ of the identity are permuted.